# Recreating MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I lost the database tables for one of my sites through a stupid mistake. I was wondering whether there is a way i can recreate them from the original PHP code. The site is custom made and I cannot find the developer. Kindly suggest the easiest method...am not a developer but am learning.

Comment: Go line by line and write `CREATE TABLE` statements for each table.

Comment: step 1) contact your hosting provider and ask to restore from backup. step 2) pray

Comment: @andrew I changed my hosting provider and forgot to dump the tables.

Comment: oops, that's a mistake you'll only make once

Comment: @tilz0R I was hoping there would be another way but i guess thats the only option

Comment: @andrew Sure...lesson learnt. Thanks though

Comment: You want to have a backup of your schema, somewhere. Did you ever take a backup of your database? Mysql backups contain a full DDL (Data Definition Language) schema, which could be extracted by someone mildly proficient with SQL and systems. This schema backup may appear like comments.

Comment: No backup. I changed my host and forgot to extract the tables. I guess the only option is to recreate the manually. Is there any possibility of my former hosting provider having a backup?

Comment: You're not going to know if you don't ask (them, not us. Obviously)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about whether or not to bother contacting a server host.